# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is doing What we think it should do?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-task

Looks like Every tutorial that we have got out there on the Web mentions that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` Starts a new task if the Activity we are starting is not currently running in the task.But it seems that using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` doesn't Creates a New Task Always, it is only Creating a new task if there is no task available for the activity we need to run like when we start an activity from a `BroadCastReceiver` using the context inside `onReceive()`.

According to the all the tutorials on the web,

Suppose We have got following activities in our BackStack-

```
A->B->C
```

Now If We want to start a new Activity D, then it should start in a New Task, but this doesn't seems to happens and the activity D is Started in the Same task and we have out final backstack

```
A->B->C->D
```

**AnyOne Who Can Clarify?**

I know setting taskAffinity will force to create a new task but this brings another problem:

Try Yourself:

Suppose we launch two Activity:

```
A-B
```

Then again we launch one other Activity with android:taskAffinity**,So now we have got**

```
A-B | C
A-B (on the same task)
C (on other task)
```

Now Again We start `A-B from C`,So now our BackStack will Look like:

```
A-B|C-A-B
A-B(on the same task)
C-A-B(on other task)
```

​

Now, the problem is If We will Again try to start C from B (from task C-A-B), nothing happens and C will not get launch (I din't know why?)